# Setting position of an element with vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, position, shadow-dom

So, I've tried getClientBoundingRect().top, elem.style.top, and all sorts of other wacky combinations, and my ultimate goal is the set one element vertically or horizontally lined up with another.  This should be a simple task, but it seems there are a lot of issues.

If the element is embedded in say, a shadow DOM, this appears to affect its location/position?  Is this supposed to be the case?  I'm using Polymer 3 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is it of type block/inline-block, or inline?

Comment: Yes this is the case for css the shadowDom is like an iframe all childs are positioned relative to this. Best would be to call getClientBoundingRect for your child elements.

Comment: If you're familiar with MS Word, and know how the "change lines" in red appear to the left or right of where a change has been made (when Track Changes is turned on) - that's kind of the idea I'm working with.  I think it's a shadowDOM issue...  

Here's the problem - getClientBoundingRect seems to be returning the correct thing, but what about *setting* the top or left of an element?  there's no "setClientBoundingRect" from what I know, and CSS top, left, etc. don't seem to be working quite right.

Comment: The invisible "line bar" I'm using to hold the red lines is a div, so it's block-level.  The ones I'm grabbing the top from for each could be anything.  Perhaps I have to test if display is equal to inline or block?  Maybe those are special cases?

Should I try to do an element.closest() to find the nearest ancestor that's a block level element?

Comment: the CSS positionning (top, left) shoud be applied to the :host pseudo-class itself